# WCF Method with parameter not generating right WSDL

Tags: wcf

I have a simple service definition:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IInterface12
{

    [OperationContract]
    void SendInterface12(string appId);
}
```

which I have implemented in the service as:

```
public void SendInterface12(string appId)
{
```

The thing is that the string parameter appId is not showing up. The complete WSDL is here:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/" name="Interface12Service">


-<wsdl:types>


-<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">

<xsd:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/" schemaLocation="http://localhost/TestInterface12/Interface12Service.svc?xsd=xsd0"/>

<xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" schemaLocation="http://localhost/TestInterface12/Interface12Service.svc?xsd=xsd1"/>

</xsd:schema>

</wsdl:types>


-<wsdl:message name="IInterface12_SendInterface12_InputMessage">

<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SendInterface12"/>

</wsdl:message>


-<wsdl:message name="IInterface12_SendInterface12_OutputMessage">

<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:SendInterface12Response"/>

</wsdl:message>


-<wsdl:portType name="IInterface12">


-<wsdl:operation name="SendInterface12">

<wsdl:input message="tns:IInterface12_SendInterface12_InputMessage" wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IInterface12/SendInterface12"/>

<wsdl:output message="tns:IInterface12_SendInterface12_OutputMessage" wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IInterface12/SendInterface12Response"/>

</wsdl:operation>

</wsdl:portType>


-<wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IInterface12" type="tns:IInterface12">

<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>


-<wsdl:operation name="SendInterface12">

<soap:operation style="document" soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IInterface12/SendInterface12"/>


-<wsdl:input>

<soap:body use="literal"/>

</wsdl:input>


-<wsdl:output>

<soap:body use="literal"/>

</wsdl:output>

</wsdl:operation>

</wsdl:binding>


-<wsdl:service name="Interface12Service">


-<wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IInterface12" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IInterface12">

<soap:address location="http://localhost/TestInterface12/Interface12Service.svc"/>

</wsdl:port>

</wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

What am I missing? I have to have a service operation that takes a parameter but when I generate the proxy, there is no parameter for the string appId parameter. It says it takes 0 parameters.

Comment: Did you try to update reference to your service? How do you generate your wsdl? What tool?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the WSDL references an XSD file where your parameter is defined. Search for "import" or "include" to see the location of that XSD. If this is your wsdl location: http://myserver.com/X.svc?WSDL=WSDL0 then the XSD is in http://myserver.com/x.svc?XSD=XSD0 (or XSD1, XSD2...). Possibly your WSDL references another WSDL (WSDL1) which is the one that references the XSD (or a few of them).

Comment: Well, one I call the method from the proxy, it doesn't have the parameter. It says that it takes no parameters.

Comment: please publish the full wsdl